# Chrome extension response passed as object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am doing chrome extension project with manifest v3.

Currently, i am working getting multiple info from contentscript.js to popup.js. I tried sending single string response from contentscript.js back to popup.js it works but when i tried sending object or json format response, it doesnt work and it shows response: undefined in popup.js

Any advice/help in sending multiple data in response will be appreciated!

Working. Able to pass response (String title) back to popup.js
contentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, response) => {

    if (message.from === "popup.js" && message.type === "RETRIEVE") {
        articleTitle = document.head.querySelector('[property="og:title"]').content;
        response(articleTitle);
    }
    return true
})
```

popup.js

```
(async () => {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        from: "popup.js",
        type: "RETRIEVE"
    });

    document.getElementById("result").innerText = response;

    console.log(response);
})();
```

========================================================================
Not working:
Unable to send response (object) back to popup.js, popup.js response is undefined

contentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, response) => {

    if (message.from === "popup.js" && message.type === "RETRIEVE") {
        var info = new Object();
        info.url = "www.website.com"
        info.title = document.head.querySelector('[property="og:title"]').content;
        console.log(info)
        response(info);
    }
    return true
})
```

popup.js

```
(async () => {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        from: "popup.js",
        type: "RETRIEVE"
    });

    document.getElementById("result").innerText = response.url;//undefined

    console.log(response); //undefined
})();
```

Comment: in the last snippet of code, if `response` is undefined, how does `document.getElementById("result").innerText = response.url` NOT throw an error?

Comment: @JaromandaX it does throw an error  on the line you mentioned``` TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')
```

Comment: try removing `return true` - that's for asynchronous responses I believe

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried removing return true, it still not working

Comment: so? I'm talking about the code in `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` is NOT asynchronous - so, don't `return true` there since you're not calling `sendResponse` (as per docs, you call the function `response`) asynchronously

Comment: Sorry, I read the MDN docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage - because they are complete unlike Chromes pathetic attempt at documenting anything - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#event-onMessage

Comment: Your code works, so the problem is something else, e.g. you need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. A simpler approach is to use executeScript ([example](/a/67227376)).